# Create a BOM file

Tags: java, maven, maven-bom

I have a Maven-based multi-module Java project that builds a number of jar files (libraries) for use by other applications.

There are 5 modules in this project, each creating a separate jar file. They all have the same version number. I would like the applications that use my libraries to be able to import a BOM file so that they can then import each individual dependency without having to specify the version number individually.

I've read lots of pages on the internet about how to *use* a BOM file, but I couldn't find out how to create one. Is there a Maven plugin or something that generates a BOM file along with the jar files when you build the project? Or is the BOM file generated in some other way? My question is how to I go about creating the BOM file for my libraries?

Comment: The close reason says "focus on one problem only", but I'd ignore that. You already *are* asking about 1 thing. The problem is more that what you're asking is unclear. A BOM to contain *what*? For what purpose? Why do you think you need one? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Michael thanks, I've edited my question to provide more context.

Comment: I voted to reopen. It's better now. You're under the misapprehension that a BOM must be generated: it doesn't have to be, and most people probably don't generate them. A BOM is just a POM with a specific purpose. It's not special. In your case, you'd probably just introduce a 6th child module called something like `myapp-bom`. The pom for that module will have packaging type `pom` (i.e. it has no associated jar) and will have a dependencyManagement section that includes dependencies on the other 5 modules. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) You can either update the 5 versions in there manually, or if you want them to always match the project version then you can use a property like `${project.version}` or `${revision}` if you're using that, and then maybe use the [flatten plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/flatten-maven-plugin/) to resolve those placeholders into a new "flattened" POM (in this case BOM) when you run your build.

Comment: @Michael ah, so this is not something generated automatically, but just a POM file that we typically create manually in a BOM module?

Comment: Yeah, that's right. Check out how this Spring project have done it. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-bom `bom` is just a module (in fact, the only module) that contains nothing but a POM - that POM *is* the BOM.

Comment: Great, thanks, that answers my question, no need to reopen.